# Сложные слова с первой частью "ретро"

Tags: орфография, словообразование, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Как пишется слово "ретро модель"? Словарь указывает — слитно, Яндекс такое написание исправляет как опечатку...
В интернете большинство пишет или раздельно, или через дефис. Может быть здесь произошло отклонение от нормы?

Answer (score 1):

Пишутся слитно сложные слова с первой иноязычной (интернациональной) частью, кончающейся на гласную. Перечень основных таких частей сложных слов с конечным о: авто-, агро-, астро-, аудио-, аэро-, баро-, бензо-, био-, вело-, вибро-, видео-, гекто-, гелио-, гео-, гетеро-, гидро-, гомо-, дендро-, зоо-, изо-, кило-, кино-, космо-, макро-, метео-, микро-, моно-, мото-, невро-, нейро-, нео-, орто-, палео-, пиро-, порно-, психо-, радио-, **ретро-,** сейсмо-, социо-, спектро-, стерео-, термо-, турбо-, фито-, фоно-, фото-, эвако-, экзо-, эко-, электро-, эндо-, энерго-

> См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006. § 117.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же первым источником совершенно правильно указали *словарь*. И никаких Яндексов, никаких интернетов. Можно посмотреть в другой словарь, в третий — чтобы убедиться окончательно.

Answer (score 0):

> Как пишется слово "ретро модель"? Словарь указывает слитно, Яндекс
>   такое написание исправляет как опечатку... В интернете большинство
>   пишет или раздельно или через дефис. Может быть здесь произошло
>   отклонение от нормы?

По факту - все слова с "ретро" пишутся слитно.
[ретро* | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE*&all=x)

Говорить об отклонении и о норме вообще — занятие довольно неблагодарное. "Норма" — понятие размытое и субъективное. Нормально было бы спросить,  есть ли правило и исключения из него. 
В данном случае все строго по правилам, о чем даже в словаре Лопатина прямо говорится.

И ещё, с каких пор "Яндекс" стал авторитетом в области правописания? Я бы этот источник не рассматривал как что-то значимое. И второе. "Ретро" — не приставка. Вообще для подобных префиксов единая терминология не сложилась, Лопатин и другие авторы называют их "первой (иноязычной) частью".

Comment: Nimand, простите не вижу более необходимости утруждать себя чтением Ваших *глупостев*. А уж спускаться до Вашего уровня, отвечая на них, простите, просто не намерен.

Comment: Я так и понял. Чего ж отвечаете не читая?

Comment: Жаль не поняли, что Вам лучше помолчать. Можете еще надувать щеки, если у Вас нет другого способа обратить на себя внимание.

Comment: Жаль, что вы не поняли (и уже вряд ли поймете), что на обиженных воду возят, дорогой *behemothus*. ))

Comment: Это-то вижу. А сколько на вас воды сейчас, дешевый Niemand? Впрочем, не буду мешать.

Comment: О! Попытка пошутить! И даже не совсем безнадежная. Безнадежная, но не совсем. Вы на правильном пути, но в самом его начале.

Answer (score 0):

Из толкового словаря на ГРАМОТЕ.РУ

РЕТРО- [ [от лат. retro - прежде, позади] Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает **отнесённость к стилю ретро**. Ретро-мелодия, ретро-мода, Ретро-открытка, ретро-показ, ретро-шлягер.

РЕТРО... [рэ] и [ре]. [лат. retro - обратно, назад] Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает **отнесённость к прошлому**. Ретроактивность, ретровирус, ретростиль.

Из этого следует дефисное написание: ретро-модель (ретро-мода).

Ретростиль  относит нас к прошлому (элемент "ретро" в роли приставки или первой основы). Ретро-мода  - здесь слово "ретро" в роли приложения.

Comment: А чем, например, отличается "ретро" от "астро"? Астро - Первая часть сложных слов. 1. Обозначает ***отнесённость чего-, кого-л. к астрономии; астрономический***. В обоих случаях часть сложного слова обозначает отнесенность к чему-либо. Тем не менее в том словаре ***ретро*** пишется через дефис, а ***астро*** - слитно.

Comment: В таких случаях следует ориентироваться на орфографический словарь.

Comment: Здесь дел не в отнесенности, а в том, что мы образуем новое слово, называя им новое понятие, или  мы имеем только определение/приложение к уже существующему предмету. Слитная форма реально применяется редко, пишут раздельно или через дефис, а это обозначение приложения.

Comment: Существует, например, слово ретроактивность, здесь "ретро" образует слово с новым значением: Ретроактивность — действие закона на решения, принятые до его вступления в силу. Обратная сила закона также именуется ретроактивностью закона или ретроактивным действием закона. Конечно же оно будет писаться слитно. А орфографическиий словарь - это не вселенский закон, в него можно внести изменение, особенно если слово имеет неустоявшееся написание, а словарей много.

Comment: Я сделал упор на слове " отнесенность" потому что вы выделили его жирным и написали: ***"Из этого следует дефисное написание: ретро-модель (ретро-мода)". ***  Вывод можно сделать из чего - отнесенности?

Comment: Если исходить из ваших слов, тогда надо писать: астро-датчик,астро-лётчик. Вторая часть - приложение.  К тому же практика письма показывает, что слова с начальным элементом на гласную (таким, как авто..., космо..., термо..., теле..., милли..., санти...) всегда писались слитно. Исключением из правила  § 117, п. 3) составляют слова  ***мини, миди, макси,диско- (муз.)***                                                                                                           («Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник». М., «АСТ-ПРЕСС», 2010).

Comment: Я просто цитировала  словарь  и подчеркивала указанное там различие в значении. По-моему, у них неплохое решение на текущий момент. Ретростиль - устоявшееся слово, пишется слитно, а все стальные "ретро" (автомобили, мода, мебель, фотографии, песни)  выполнены в ретростиле и пишутся через дефис.

Comment: Ну тогда надо писать : ***астро-датчик,астро-лётчик*** исхордя из этой практики. Кстати, та же Грамота советует ориентироваться на орфографический словарь, а не толковый.

Comment: В том же словаре ***масс-медиа*** , в орфографическом массмедиа. Там вообще много отличий от орфографического словаря.Я писал им, хотел узнать, на основе какого правила, например, в толковом словаре дается дефисное написание ***масс-медиа. ретро-мода***. Увы, ответа не последовало.

Comment: Многие обращаются с этим вопросом, но они ни как не комментируют, лишь отвечают: в подобных случаях следует ориентироваться на рекомендации орфографического словаря: ***сложные слова с первой частью ретро- пишутся слитно: ретростиль, ретроавтомобиль***.

Comment: Астродатчик - это не разновидность какого-то обобщенного датчика, а  особая конструкция для ориентирования по звездам,  скорее сложный прибор, чем датчик, поэтому для него дефисное написание не подойдет. Да и космонавт - это тоже особая профессия.

Comment: Тогда попросите их прокомментировать словарь на ГРАМОТЕ-РУ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39187/discussion-between--and-sibylla).

Comment: Так я же говорю, они не отвечают.

Comment: А вот почему мы пишем микрочастица, но мини-компьютер, как Вы думаете? Можно это как-то объяснить?

Comment: Знаете, есть интересная статья "минивэн или мини-вэн". К сожалению, здесь ссылку не могу дать, громоздкая. Вбейте в поисковик, найдете. Там подробно объясняется.

Comment: "Тогда попросите их прокомментировать словарь на ГРАМОТЕ-РУ." - Sybilia, *толковый* словарь на грамоте один. Это Кузнецов. Не надо использовать его как орфографический. Это совершенно несопоставимые вещи. А уж просить что-то комментировать можно только самого Кузнецова. Но к его детищу уже накопилось столько вопросов, что он просто перестал отвечать даже на запросы от самой редакции "Грамоты".

Comment: А вот у Лопатина (там же) - да, словарь *орфографический*. И ясно сказано, что слова подобные пишутся слитно. Но там другое. Речь идет о *существующих* естественных словах. В отношении новообразований подобное не обязано выполняться. Поэтому дефис мне тоже нравится в отдельных случаях, о которых вы говорите. Всё сказанное не имеет никого отношения к идее Сержа писать подобным образом сочетания с "астро-" - здесь другая семантика и могут быть другие правила.

Comment: Я думаю, что семантика слова должна определять его орфографию, а не наоборот,  она должна считываться со структуры слова, поэтому к толковым словарям я отношусь с большим вниманием. И если Кузнецов так плох, то почему его на ГРАМОТЕ.РУ не заменят другим словарем. Или не на что менять?

Comment: Вот у Лопатина ясно сказано, что слова с "ретро" пишутся слитно, вот если бы он так же ясно сказал, почему они пишутся слитно, причем именно ВСЕ  слова.  У нас же есть прецеденты разного написания иноязычных формантов, например: контрреволюция и контр-адмирал, блокпост и блок-схема, обер-лейтенант и обертон.

Answer (score 0):

Это не отклонение от нормы, это изменение нормы. Речь снова о [реформе орфографии 2000г.](http://www.wikiznanie.ru/wikipedia/index.php/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81,_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Изменения 2000 г.: Распространить правило свода 1956 г. о слитном написании сложных слов с начальными компонентами типа аэро-, авиа- (§78, п. 1) на образования с появившимися в последние десятилетия компонентами аудио-, видео-, диско-, макси-, медиа-, миди-, мини-, ретро- (среди них — такие, которые до сих пор обычно пишутся через дефис). Писать: аудиоаппаратура, видеомагнитофон,дискоклуб, максиюбка, медиахолдинг, мидимода, минитрактор, ретромузыка и т. п.

Раньше было разделение, о чём пишет Sibylla:

Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает отнесённость к стилю ретро. Ретро-мелодия, ретро-мода, ретро-открытка, ретро-показ, ретро-шлягер.

Образования, состоящие из сущ. и несклоняемого несогласованного определения, стоящего после определяемого сущ., пишутся раздельно: модель  ретро. Если определение стоит ПЕРЕД определяемым сущ., то такие образования пишутся через дефис: ретро-модель

Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает отнесённость к прошлому. Ретровирус= ретровый вирус=вирус из прошлого, ретростиль=ретровый стиль= стиль из прошлого.

Но теперь можно всё это забыть и писать всё слитно

Comment: Людмила, не могли бы вы исправить ссылку. Она не открывается.

Comment: Кстати, я правильно понял: по старому правилу надо писать ***ретро-флексия***?

Comment: Нет, слитно, это не имеет отношения к стилю "ретро".   Ретрофлексия -это процесс возврата чувств назад, точно против себя.

Comment: http://www.wikiznanie.ru/wikipedia/index.php/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81,_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Comment: Спасибо........